# OGM/ORM for OrientDB

Tags: java, orm, orientdb, graph-databases, tinkerpop3

I am looking for a OGM for OrientDb - something that will allow me to persist my domain model (POJO) as vertices and edges declaratively (using annotations perhaps). I stumbled upon `Ferma` which seems to have the annotations support but I can't find many examples to go on. Specifically, how do I create/initialise a `Ferma` `FramedGraph` from an `OrientGraphFactory`?

This lack of enough samples/documentation also makes me doubt the support for `Ferma`. I am new to graph databases. Am I on the right track? Are OGM/ORM not the right way to go for graph databases or am I just looking at the wrong OGM? Coming from the RDBM world I am looking for a stack like: `OrientDb` -> `TinkerPop3 Frames` -> `anOGM` where `anOGM` is an actively maintained fast(preferably compile time code generation) OGM/ORM with wide community support. Something like `neo4j-ogm`.

Yes, JPA has spoiled me!!.

Comment: **Ferma is by far the most active OGM**. It has 537 commits, 20 stable releases, and 11 contributors. Compare that with gremlin-orm which has only 1 contributor, 28 commits, and not a single stable release.

It even has extensions specifically for OrientDB.

Answer (score 2):

Currently, the most active OGM for TinkerPop 3.x that I know of for Java is the recently announced [gremlin-ogm](https://github.com/karthicks/gremlin-ogm). You also have the option of building a [Gremlin DSL](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#dsl) which has a similar goal of mapping the domain of the graph to the query language. You can read more about that here in this [blog post](https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/gremlin-dsls-in-java-with-dse-graph) as well.

Comment: **Ferma is considerably more active than gremlin-orm**. IT has 20 stable releases and 537 commits, and 11 contributors under its belt and still going strong. Gremlin-orm by comparison has only 28 commits and not a single stable release, and only one contributor.

Comment: Hi.
I have developed a ODBOGM mapper. You can find it in https://github.com/mdre/odbogm